# How to get the ID from a newly created database entry for a redirect - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using MongoDB and Mongoose with Node.JS. I am trying to save too a database and get the newly created ID for the redirect. I understand save() can get the id as a callback. However, I am getting the error: *SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target* on the argument req.body in the line

Count.save(err, **req.body**) => {

The full code:

```
// @desc    Process the count form
// @route   POST /session/create
router.post('/session/create', async (req, res) => {
    req.body.user = req.user.id
    await Count.save(err, req.body) => {
        if(err) { 
            next(err); 
        }
        const itemID = req.body._id;
        res.redirect('/new-page' + itemID);
    }
});
```

Count.create(req.body) will create the entry in the database but my understanding is it wont return the id. I don't understand why req.body is a valid argument in one instance and not another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer. Had to create the instance first, then pass the information in. Below is the working POST request and as a bonus the redirected GET request

```
// @desc    Process the count form
// @route   POST /session/create
router.post('/create', (req, res) => {
    let session = new Count();
    session.name = req.body.name;
    session.email = req.body.email;
    session.user = req.user.id
    session.save(function (err, start) {
        if(err)
        {console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(start.id)
        }
    });
    console.log(session.id)
    res.redirect('/session/' + session.id)
});


// @desc    Continuation of session 
// @route   GET /session/:id
router.get('/:id', ensureAuth, (req, res) => {
        res.render('session/add')
});
```